# Oracle SQL Developer 23.1: DBA->Instance viewer->MEMORY/STORAGE nothing is displayed

Tags: oracle, installation, database-administration

On a new Windows 11 jump host, I just installed Oracle SQL Developer 23.1, and I am not seeing a specific tab under 'DBA.' DBA->Instance Viewer -> "MEMORY/STORAGE" nothing is displayed while TOP SQL is fine. Here are some screenshots:
[image: top sql] [image: memory-storage]

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

I have encountered the same issue on my laptop in a previous version and other clients, so I suppose there might be some sort of dependency of which I am unaware.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a bug. You can see note 2965096.1 on support.oracle.com. Depending on your java version, adding this to you product.conf file may help

```
AddVMOption -Djavafx.allowjs=true
```